# Chrome how to get the browser zoom level (from touchpad or mouse wheel)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, browser

I am trying to get the browser's zoom level with JS. **Not the built in zoom** (by using command  and + or -) but the zoom when the user resizes the window with touchpad or mouse wheel.

I tried for example with the Chrome API `chrome.tabs.getZoom()` but this gets the zoom option size.

Also `devicePixelRatio` just gets the DPI and is always 2.

I need this because I'm drawing an area in a web page which I will crop with canvas. I'm able to get the correct tab window screenshot (whether zoomed in or not) but the cropping is off if zoomed in (using touchpad or mouse wheel)

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is because 1) *resizing* of a window doesn't change its zoom level, 2) Ctrl/Command key with a mouse wheel is the same as Ctrl and +- key.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly...

You have no idea when a document body is zoomed and at the risk of your cropping being off you’re looking for a way to calculate the cropping size/area correctly, right?

If that's the problem then I would do this:

Given... W = your frame/window ID, then:

```
var B=W.contentWindow.document.body;


var Z=W.contentWindow.getComputedStyle(B,null).getPropertyValue('zoom');


// Assuming you are cropping a rectangle then...


Crop_X1*=Z;

Crop_Y1*=Z;

Crop_X2*=Z; 

Crop_Y2*=Z;
```

In other words, just multiply your acquired cropping coordinates by the zoom factor.

Comment: The issue is how to get the zoom value.